# Is there a way to modify a string to keep only sentences with punctuation?

Tags: java, string

So, I'm looking to modify a string in Java. Here is an example:

`String text = "This is some text. I want to keep certain portions of it. I only want to keep sentences with punctuation. This is not an example of a sentence that should be kept This is an example of text that should be kept. How would I do this?"; text = text.replace("","")`

I don't know what to place in the code to replace the current string with only sentences with punctuation at the end of them in order to remove the text that says: "This is not an example of a sentence that should be kept"

Thank you for your help in advance. (I have modified this question because I am trying to extract only sentences from a string, not just the last sentence of a string without punctuation.)

Comment: `text.replaceAll("(?<=[.!?])[^.!?]*$", "")`?

Comment: Maybe `text = text.replaceAll("(\\w.*\\.).*", "$1");
`

Comment: What you're looking for in a sentence is a String that begins with an upper-case letter and ends with a period and a space.  Your non-sentence ends with a space.

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for... code snippet I can work from to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :

```
String punctuatedText = text.substring(0,text.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
```

But it will only work if you want to remove the last sentence if it doesn't has punctuation at the end.